# Convert INT to text with new values within SQL View

Tags: sql-server, sql-view

I have a view which returns 4 columns, Date (filtered by day using `datediff`), Quantity, Document number.

The field Document Number returns an integer (1-8) but I need it to return for example (1 = Warehouse, 2 = Office, etc etc) Unfortunately, these values don't exist anywhere in the database.

Any help would be appreciated, on how to achieve this and whether this can stay within a view or has to be done via SQL query instead

Comment: If you are using a version of SQL that doesn't support Choose the you could use a Case statement

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `CHOOSE()`

**Example**

```
Select choose(SomeIntValue,'Warehouse','Office', ...)
 From  YourTable
```